# jQuery.post() and modifying div HTML every X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple line of HTML code:

```
<div id="bio">Something...</div>
```

And then I have some jQuery code. It should be very fast. This is important. I do not want to kill the browser, but the code must be executed every 5 seconds.

So, the problem is that I do not which code is the best one, A) or B).

A)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  get_bio_data = function() {
    var bio = 106;

    jQuery.post("get_bio.php", {
      bio: bio
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#bio').html(data);

      setTimeout(get_bio_data, 5000);
    });
  };

  setTimeout(get_bio_data, 5000);
});
```

B)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function get_bio_data() {
    var
      bio = 106,
      old_bio = document.getElementById('bio');

    jQuery.post("get_bio.php", {
      bio: bio
    }).done(function(data) {
      var new_bio = document.createElement('div');
      new_bio.innerHTML = data;
      new_bio.id = 'bio';

      old_bio.parentNode.replaceChild(new_bio, old_bio);
      old_bio = new_bio;

      setTimeout(get_bio_data, 5000);
    });
  };

  setTimeout(get_bio_data, 5000);
});
```

I also would like to know if A) and B) both are 100% cross-browser solutions or not if jQuery/JavaScript is enabled on the browser.

Or should I forget both of them and do something else instead?

Comment: Your snippets look like they will behave differently. In the second you call function... My suggestion is to write variant C, in plain js, as far as you're talking about performance, that will be the best. And what do you mean, by killing browser? :)

Comment: @Lazyexpert I modified B) a liitle bit. I do not know how to do this with pure JavaScript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: In terms of "killing the browser", the AJAX call is doing a lot more damage than DOM manipulation. That said, A is probably more performant

Comment: @code_monk I cannot see how A) is calling AJAX less than B). Could you please explain, thanks.

Comment: And if you're talking about browser kill, there must be.... Idk, at least, 100 calls a minute. Are you sure, you're solving the right problem?

Comment: @Lazyexpert The code should be executed every 5 seconds.

Comment: I've just realized the sense of your functions.. its kind of heartbeating some data. I would suggest websocket to do that.

Comment: @Lazyexpert It seems to me that Internet Explorer does not support WebSocket.

Comment: @xms (A) is not making more  AJAX calls than (B). (A) is slightly more performant because it does slightly less DOM manipulation.

Comment: Only change the content if it changes.... No need to write it in plain JavaScript.... Just swap out the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JavaScript is *very* fast. Except if you will execute this code at least ten times per second, you will most likely not even notice any performance difference.

So my advice is to focus on writing readable and maintainable code, instead of  performance. If you choose to use jQuery, then you should definitly use option A. And if performance is *really* that important to you (which I doubt), you should not be using jQuery at all, but go for plain JavaScript.

Secondly, JavaScript is available in any browser, and you should probably not even bother to support people who have disabled JavaScript as most of the web is inaccessible to them anyway.

Also note that Ajax is asynchronous, meaning it will not freeze the rest of your application. The DOM manipulations will probably be the most costly, so when optimizing you should try avoid those as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks. Why would you use A) instead of B)?

Comment: @xms Because it's very clear what it does, it is very readable, which makes it maintainable. And as I mentioned, performance-wise there's not much of a difference

Comment: And you think that A) is faster?

Comment: Sure, it's faster.. You should try it out and see if you notice the speed improvement